# How to add result to resultset of a MySQL stored procedure in java

Tags: java, database, stored-procedures, resultset

I want to add the results to the resultset and use table to display the results
it's my java code

```
while (resultSet.next()) {

            Object[] objects = {
                    resultSet.getDouble("January"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("February"), 
                    resultSet.getDouble("March"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("April"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("May"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("June"), 
                    resultSet.getDouble("July"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("August"), 
                    resultSet.getDouble("September"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("October"), 
                    resultSet.getDouble("November"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("December"), 
                     };
            model.addRow(objects);
        }
```

The error shows "Column 'Janunary' not found."

I am sorry that I haven't earn sufficient reputation, so I write the result of stored procedure as follows.

```
categoryid  January   February....

1      3000      5000      (double)....
```

The Query code:

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
        if (cobAccount.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            String accountid = cobAccount.getSelectedItem().toString()
                    .substring(0, 1);
            callableStatement.setString(1, accountid);
        } else {
            callableStatement.setString(1, "0");
        }
        if (cobYear.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            String year = cobYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
            callableStatement.setString(2, year);
        } else {
            callableStatement.setString(2, "0");
        }
        if (cobMember.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            String memberid = cobMember.getSelectedItem().toString()
                    .substring(0, 1);
            callableStatement.setString(3, memberid);
        } else {
            callableStatement.setString(3, "0");
        }
        if (!"".equals(txtMinmoney.getText())) {
            double minMoney = Double.valueOf(txtMaxmoney.getText());
            callableStatement.setDouble(4, minMoney);
        } else {
            callableStatement.setDouble(4, '0');
        }
        if (!"".equals(txtMaxmoney.getText())) {
            double maxMoney = Double.valueOf(txtMaxmoney.getText());
            callableStatement.setDouble(5, maxMoney);
        } else {
            callableStatement.setDouble(5, '0');
        }
```

Comment: is it a typo your code shows Janunary which I firmly believe should be January

Comment: I have corrected it,but it also can't find the column.Column 'January' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the string you pass for the `getDouble` function are the actual names of your SQL columns. For example, *Janunary* does not seem to be spelled correctly.

Comment: Try removing January column and see if it works for the rest. If it works, there is a typo somewhere for your January column, either in your code, either in the database column name.

Comment: If I remove January coloumn,it display "Column 'February' not found.".

Answer (score 0):

you skip January with your `resultSet.next()` no?

maybe do `resultSet.hasNext()` or equivelant and `resultSet.next()` at the end of your loop?

Comment: If I change to hasNext(), it ask me to change to next() or add cast to resultset.  And you mean using "do while"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't a column named January.  Is there a column named "Month" with a value of Jan/Feb/etc?  If you could post the table definition and query, troubleshooting would be easier.

Comment: What's the definition about table?The coloumn names?It's also from January to December.The query code I have updated.

Comment: The column names were the part I was curious about.  If they are January through December, it's most likely a spelling error between column names in the DB and column names in Java.  Remember that they are case sensitive.  Also, you could switch to rs.getDouble(1), rs.getDouble(2)... if your query returns them in the desired order.